# Plot against date but show something else as labels on x axis

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I have the following data:

```
var data = [{ 
         "value": 1,
         "version": 1.0,
         "datetime": "2009-04-26 18:06:43"
},{
         "value": 2,
         "version": 2.0,
         "datetime": "2009-04-27 06:05:53"
},{
         "value": 2,
         "version": 2.1,
         "datetime": "2009-04-28 15:21:53"
},{    
         "value": 1,
         "version": 1.0,
         "datetime": "2009-04-29 13:51:24"
}];
```

I want to create a line chart with x axis as date. See http://jsfiddle.net/y1o52tk4/3/

But instead of showing datetime as labels on x axis, I want to display the corresponding version value for that datetime. Any ideas on how can I do this?

Comment: Use a custom axis tick format and check the date against the version. Return the version.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about using xAxis().tickFormat  
If I use datetime then the values of d that this function receives doesn’t match my data.  
I also updated my jsfiddle.
`Mon Apr 27 2009 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)  
Mon Apr 27 2009 06:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)    
Mon Apr 27 2009 12:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
Mon Apr 27 2009 18:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
Tue Apr 28 2009 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
Tue Apr 28 2009 06:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
Tue Apr 28 2009 12:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
Tue Apr 28 2009 18:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
Wed Apr 29 2009 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
Wed Apr 29 2009 06:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)`

Comment: Right, because the axis is trying to make ticks at 6 hour intervals. There is a method `.ticks()` of axis, with which you can specify ticks more explicitly -- either as intervals (eg a tick per day) or  as an array of dates. Unless you always have one release on every day, you probably want to use the array of dates options. In that case you should expect to see date ticks at irregular intervals.

Comment: @meetamit Thanks! I used `.xAxis().tickValues(["Mon Apr 27 2009 06:05:53 GMT-0700 (PDT)", "Wed Apr 29 2009 13:51:24 GMT-0700 (PDT)"]).tickFormat(function(d){
            return d;
        });` and got an error `Error: Invalid value for <g> attribute transform="translate(NaN,0)"`. See http://jsfiddle.net/y1o52tk4/5/

Comment: Ahh, my dates should have been objects returned by d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %X").parse